# Select even number of items from each relation

Tags: django, postgresql, tastypie

I am using Tastypie for our API and one endpoint needs to show a list of places in specific categories.
That part is easy:

```
class PlaceResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Place.objects.all()
        filtering = { 
            'category': ALL
        }
```

But say I have a `limit = 100`, I would like to get an even number of places from each category.

**Example:**

*/api/places/?category=1&category=2&category=3&category=4*

Should give me 25 places from each category 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I know I can use SQL to do so, but how is that done in an optimal way?

Comment: You can certainly do it in SQL. Doing it *efficiently* will be another matter. The obvious solution is a `UNION ALL` of four subqueries, each with `LIMIT`s. That won't be pretty as the number of requested categories grows, though.

Comment: How would you deal with a case where only 20 rows are found for category 1?

Answer (score 1):

Say, we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE place (
   place_id serial primary key
 , place    text
 , cat_id   int);
```

[Test setup on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/87c84/2).
You would profit from an index on `category` like demonstrated in the setup.

Basically, I see two different ways:

#### [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS rn
    FROM   place
    WHERE  category IN (1,2,3,4)
    )
SELECT place_id, place, category
FROM   x
ORDER  BY rn
LIMIT  100;
```

- Besides being rather elegant, the only part where this query gets longer with more categories is the `IN` clause.
- No need to calculate the share for each `category`, that happens automatically.
- If there are fewer rows for a category than its share would be, the rest is filled with the other categories in equal shares.

#### [`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

```
(SELECT * FROM place WHERE category = 1 LIMIT 25)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM place WHERE category = 2 LIMIT 25)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM place WHERE category = 3 LIMIT 25)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM place WHERE category = 4 LIMIT 25);
```

- This is primitive and *very fast*, but gets longish (though not slow) for many categories.
- Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.
- Parenthesis around each leg of the `UNION` query are needed to apply `LIMIT`.
- You need to calculate the share for each category, and decide how to split fractional shares.
- If there are fewer rows for a category than its share would be, you get fewer rows out of the query.